# Is there a better way to handle the path to the .app file when testing React Native apps using Appium?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, react-native, appium, watir-webdriver

I'm just getting my feet wet testing React Native apps and I was wondering whether there was an easier way to path to the app in the appium.txt file. That file looks like this:

```
[caps]
platformName = "ios"
deviceName = "iPhone 6"
platformVersion = "9.2"
waitForAppScript = true
app = "Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/923C1612-25BA-4206-9109-5C0B65B08897/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/B91B9D4B-5A95-4576-86D5-94060F7F3680/myapp.app"

[appium_lib]
sauce_username = false
sauce_access_key = false
```

the `app =` portion handles the path to the actual app file that appium will run my test suite against (I'm current using cucumber and watir-webdriver) but the problem is that every time I run that app from Xcode, the app UDID changes. Is there a better way to do this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Clearing out, `app =` portion handles the path to the actual app on your local storage. How is the change in UDID a problem to your app path then?

Comment: Though I am entirely new to ruby/cucumber, tried looking for some solution to your problem, seems like you want to modify the app path at runtime similar to the way the device `caps` is modified in the support file for environments here : https://github.com/appium/sample-code/blob/master/sample-code/examples/ruby/cucumber_ios/features/support/env.rb

Comment: If I understood your question, you are using Xcode to build app, rather than using xcode, you can use xcode command line: xcodebuild, to build your app and in command you can specify a fixed path where your app file will always be created, and that app path you can use in your appium.txt file.

Comment: Thanks all, @Pankaj was helpful in getting further along in this. I also found out how to set it in xCode so that it overrides to that even when you build from command line. @nullpointer also taught me something new in regards to multiple `caps` files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting relative path in **`app=.../.../YOUR_PATH_TO_THE_APP/YOUR_APP.app`**
will do the trick. It will take the app from that location and fire it up. 
No need to bother with XCode builds.

Please see here example: [image: appium.txt]